# Mongo DB Aggregation pipeline help for nested document building

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Tried many ways in mongodb aggregation and pipeline concepts but not able to achieve exactly the below format required for my project.

My data in Mongodb collection is in the below format

```
[{
    "title" : "Product Title 1",
    "desc" : "Product Description 1",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "A"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 2",
    "desc" : "Product Description 2",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "A"
},,
{
    "title" : "Product Title 3",
    "desc" : "Product Description 3",
    "year" : 2018,
    "productkey" : "A"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 4",
    "desc" : "Product Description 4",
    "year" : 2018,
    "productkey" : "A"
},
[{
    "title" : "Product Title 5",
    "desc" : "Product Description 5",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "B"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 6",
    "desc" : "Product Description 6",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "B"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 7",
    "desc" : "Product Description 7",
    "year" : 2018,
    "productkey" : "B"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 8",
    "desc" : "Product Description 8",
    "year" : 2018,
    "productkey" : "B"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 9",
    "desc" : "Product Description 9",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "C"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 10",
    "desc" : "Product Description 10",
    "year" : 2019,
    "productkey" : "C"
},
{
    "title" : "Product Title 11",
    "desc" : "Product Description 11",
    "year" : 2018,
    "productkey" : "C"
}]
```

I am trying to achieve the below format using aggregation and pipelines

```
[{
    "productkey" : "A",
    "details":
    [
        {
            "year": 2019,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 1",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 1",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 2",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 2",
                }           
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2018,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 3", "desc" : "Product Description 3",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 4",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 4",
                }           
            ]

        } 
    ]
},
{
    "productkey" : "B",
    "details":
    [
        {
            "year": 2019,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 5",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 5",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 6",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 6",
                }           
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2018,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 7",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 7",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 8",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 8",
                }           
            ]

        } 
    ]
},
{
    "productkey" : "C",
    "details":
    [
        {
            "year": 2019,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 9",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 9",
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 10",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 10",
                }           
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2018,
            "subdetails":[
                {
                    "title" : "Product Title 11",
                    "desc" : "Product Description 11",
                }       
            ]

        } 
    ]
}]
```

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "productkey": "$productkey", "year": "$year" },
    "subDetails": { "$push": { "title": "$title", "desc": "$desc" }}
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.productkey",
    "details": { "$push": { "year": "$_id.year", "subDetails": "$subDetails" }}
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oSXg2VxgCmx)

Comment: is it possible to sort by year in above solution at details level ?

Comment: Add one `$sort` stage in between both the `$group`

Comment: { $sort: { "details.year": 1 } } tried this adding between groups , but no luck

Comment: `{ $sort: { "_id.year": 1 } }`